# Не отображается текст в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу отобразить количество очков и количество жизни у игрока при помощи класса `GUI.Label`. Часть этого кода выглядит так:

```
void onGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 60, 20), "Score: " + player.score.ToString());
        GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 30, 60, 20), "Score: " + player.lives.ToString());
}
```

Но после запуска проекта этих меток нет. Так же, я пробовал создавать новый проект и копировать код, который указан в официальной справке. Там так же ничего не показывается. Есть идеи?
 Unity3D 5.2.1f1
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By40bSw4WlDGNi1TT2hFdThnNWM/view?usp=sharing
Дополнение: 
Даже если поместить в новый проект вот этот код из официальной справки с разноцветными кнопками, ничего нет после запуска:

```
void OnGUI() {
        GUI.color = Color.yellow;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), "Hello World!");
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 50, 50, 50), "A BOX");
        GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 110, 70, 30), "A button");
    }
```

Дополнение: 
 В общем, комментарий Павла выручил меня. Нужно было добавить скрипт на камеру. Но забавность в том, что видимо в предыдущих версиях Unity в этом не было необходимости. Поэтому, большая часть теоретических курсов содержит этот код метода onGUI в тех скриптах, которые отвечают, например, за игрока, и скрипт мог находиться на совершенно другом объекте.
 P.S. Модераторы, как комментарий сделать правильным ответом?

Comment: Точно нет, или выводит 5 шрифтом, что чуть видно?

Comment: Его там точно нет. Я несколько попыток сделал. И на Mac и на win пк. На пустых проектах. Метки по каким то причинам не появляются.

Comment: Совсем тупой вопрос, скрипт точно на камере висит?

Comment: И да, гуи только при запуске показывается, не в предпросмотре.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии 4.6 Unity 3D использует новую систему UI с возможностью редактирования интерфейса в режиме WYSIWYG. Больше не нужно работать с интерфейсом в onGUI, поскольку введена система событий.

Для начала нужно в проект добавить Ui->Canvas потом на него повесить компонент Text и на этот компонент привязать скрипт:

```
private void Start()
 {
   Text  mytext= GetComponent<Text>();
   mytext.text = "Привет SoR!";
 }
```

Вот небольшое видеообзор по теме: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOX6itCuKOc

Comment: >>Больше не нужно работать с интерфейсом в onGUI, поскольку введена система событий. @AnatolyNikolaev
Не соглашусь что "не нужно", отрисовка в OnGUI шустрее, и более гибкая, более того, если начать писать на UI - то нельзя смешивать "самодельную" рисовку и UI, так как самоделка рисуется последним слоем, и UI уже не вытащить на передний план.

Comment: В остальном - вопрос привычки, имхо, удобней самому добавить Editor и рисовать в режиме WYSIWYG чтобы дизайнеры это дело видели, но, сэкономить часть ресурсов (самодельному коду не всегда важны анкеры, масштабирование и ряд неиспользуемых свойств рисовки), нежели лепить UI и пытаться строить костыли в "трудных местах" :D